# NSubstitute: Checking DidNotReceive async method

Tags: .net-core, nsubstitute

Given an async method, how can NSubstitute check a call was not received?

With NSubstitute, we can check a async method (or many) were received in order using:

```cs
Received.InOrder(async () =>
{
    await client.SendAsync(Arg.Any<string>())
});
```

What is the equivalent for `DidNotReceive`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created/answered my own question here because I found this unintuitive in NSubstitute.

```cs
await client.DidNotReceive().SendAsync(Arg.Any<string>());
```

Comment: It is described in the documentation at https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/